# « Pour exemple » et « par exemple »

Tags: usage, prépositions

La forme courante est je crois *par exemple*. Par contre, puisque *pour* est defini comme

> Comme, en fait de, en guise de, en tant que

dans le thésaurus, je pense que *pour exemple* est même plus précis que *par exemple*, car usuellement on dit quelque chose **pour** donner un exemple d'un concept plus général et pas lorsqu'on arrive à formuler un concept général par une série d’exemples. Est-ce que je me trompe ? Si oui pourquoi ?

Comment: Je ne comprends pas la question. On ne dit pas « pour exemple » en français, ça ressemble à une faute de frappe pour « par exemple ».

Comment: En revanche, on a parfois la construction *« prendre **pour exemple** »*. Mais en effet, *pour exemple* tout seul ne convient pas en lieu et place de *par exemple*.

Comment: _Pour *l'*exemple_ peut-être?

Comment: @Unfrancophone Ca existe aussi, oui, mais c'est un usage un peu différent. *Les élèves étaient dissipés : j'en ai puni deux pour l'exemple. // Mais quel trublion ont-ils pris pour exemple?*

Comment: @RomainVALERI. Je pense que le sense que j'avais dans la tete est tout affait celui-la. Mais je vois que la question n'est pas très bien posé. Dés que j'aurais un peu de temps je écrirais une nouvelle questionne avec quelque exemple.

Comment: Quelqu'un va-t-y finir par corriger c'te titre que j'avais raté (les fautes les plus grosses...) et qui comporte encore "exAmple"? C'est un mauvais "exemple" pour ceux qui viennent nous lire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si un exemple est souvent un cas particulier illustrant un modèle général (*Les arbres sont verts, **par** exemple le platane*), le terme fonctionne souvent pour indiquer le modèle lui même. On utilise alors le modèle (donc, ici, l'exemple), par le principe de la copie, de l'imitation. (si je ne suis pas clair, dites le moi).

C'est même sa première définition, telle que la donne [le tlfi](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?12;s=2824333845;r=1;nat=;sol=1;) :

> Personne, action, activité qui peut être proposée comme modèle à
>   imiter.

Et on dit alors **pour** l'exemple : *Punir pour l'exemple*.

Et cela découle des définitions de par et de pour, il me semble ?

Il est vrai qu'on dit plutôt *pour l'exemple*, mais je pense que *pour exemple* est aussi correct, mais je ne suis pas Grevisse.

Comment: Cette réponse est un peu plus proche de l'autre au point que j'ai essayé d'expliquer.

Answer (score 8):

"*pour exemple*" est plutôt un synonyme de "*comme exemple*" alors que "*par exemple*" signifie "*pour donner un exemple*".